# How to replace every NaN in a column with different random values using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, random, normal-distribution

I have been playing with pandas lately and I now I tried to replace NaN value inside a dataframe with different random value of normal distribution.

Assuming I have this CSV file without header

```
      0
0    343
1    483
2    101
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
```

My expected result should be something like this

```
       0
0     343
1     483
2     101
3     randomnumber1
4     randomnumber2
5     randomnumber3
```

But instead I got the following :

```
       0
0     343
1     483
2     101
3     randomnumber1
4     randomnumber1
5     randomnumber1    # all NaN filled with same number
```

My code so far

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv", header=None)
mu, sigma = df.mean(), df.std()
norm_dist = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1)
for i in norm_dist:
    print df.fillna(i)
```

I am thinking to get the number of NaN row from the dataframe, and replace the number 1 in `np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1)` with the total of NaN row so each NaN might have different value.

But I want to ask if there is other simple method to do this?

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: both solutions are working just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way working with underlying array data -

```
def fillNaN_with_unifrand(df):
    a = df.values
    m = np.isnan(a) # mask of NaNs
    mu, sigma = df.mean(), df.std()
    a[m] = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=m.sum())
    return df
```

In essence, we are generating all random numbers in one go with the count of NaNs using the [size param with `np.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal) and assigning them in one go with the mask of the NaNs again.

Sample run -

```
In [435]: df
Out[435]: 
       0
0  343.0
1  483.0
2  101.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN

In [436]: fillNaN_with_unifrand(df)
Out[436]: 
            0
0  343.000000
1  483.000000
2  101.000000
3  138.586483
4  223.454469
5  204.464514
```

Comment: I take that you are showing me what I should done if I want to use my method of counting the NaN row right? I did not think of this way at first. Thank you for showing it

Comment: @Fang Yes that `m.sum()` basically gets you the count of NaNs that could be fed to `np.random.normal()` as the size param, thus giving us exactly the number of rand numbers needed in one go and thus achieve a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple to impute random values in place of missing values in a pandas DataFrame column.

```
mean = df['column'].mean()
std = df['column'].std()

def fill_missing_from_Gaussian(column_val):
    if np.isnan(column_val) == True: 
        column_val = np.random.normal(mean, std, 1)
    else:
         column_val = column_val
return column_val
```

Now just apply the above method to a column with missing values.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(fill_missing_from_Gaussian)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
mu, sigma = df.mean(), df.std()
#get mask of NaNs
a = df[0].isnull()
#get random values by sum ot Trues, processes like 1
norm_dist = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, a.sum())
print (norm_dist)
[ 184.90581318  364.89367364  181.46335348]
#assign values by mask
df.loc[a, 0] = norm_dist
print (df)

            0
0  343.000000
1  483.000000
2  101.000000
3  184.905813
4  364.893674
5  181.463353
```