# Fill NaN values in a column within a specific range of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am wanting to do the following:

Fill NaN values in a single column using values within a specific range.

The range I am wanting to use is the mean of the non-Nan values in the column +/- 1 one standard
deviation of the computed mean.

*NOTE* If possible, I would like to be able to use multiples of the std dev by simply multiplying it by
a constant.

I thought I had it (see full code below) but the output from `print(df['C'].describe())` shows that
I am generating values well outside my desired range.  In fact, I am generating numbers outside
the original min and max of the column, which is definitely not what I want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys

print('Python: {}'.format(sys.version))
print('NumPy: {}'.format(np.__version__))
print('Pandas: {}'.format(pd.__version__))
print('\033[1;31m' + '--------------' + '\033[0m')  # Bold red

display_settings = {
    'max_columns': 15,
    'max_colwidth': 60,
    'expand_frame_repr': False,  # Wrap to multiple pages
    'max_rows': 50,
    'precision': 6,
    'show_dimensions': False
}
# pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

for op, value in display_settings.items():
    pd.set_option("display.{}".format(op), value)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(200, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
# df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20, 4)), columns=list(['AA','BB','C2','D2']))
print(df, '\n')

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149738/pandas-replace-values-with-nan-at-random
df['C'] = df['C'].sample(frac=0.65)  # The percentage of non-NaN values.
df['H'] = df['H'].sample(frac=0.75)  # The percentage of non-NaN values.
print(df, '\n')
print(df.isnull().sum(), '\n')
print(df['C'].describe(), '\n')

def fillNaN_with_unifrand(col):
    a = col.values
    m = np.isnan(a)  # mask of NaNs
    mu, sigma = col.mean(), col.std()
    a[m] = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=m.sum())
    return col


# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543060/how-to-replace-every-nan-in-a-column-with-different-random-values-using-pandas?rq=1
fillNaN_with_unifrand(df['C'])
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format
print(df, '\n')
print(df.isnull().sum(), '\n')
print(df['C'].describe())
```

Output of `print(df['C'].describe())`:

Starting:

```
count    130.000000
mean     462.446154
std      290.760432
min        7.000000
25%      187.500000
50%      433.000000
75%      671.250000
max      992.000000
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Ending:

```
count    200
mean     517
std      298
min     -187
25%      281
50%      544
75%      763
max     1218
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Note the min and max.  All of my fill values (in this instance) should have been 462 +/- 290.

Comment: Been reading the docs.  Doesn't appear to be an upper\lower limit on np.random.normal.  I changed to using sigma*0.5 and I have not gone outside the starting min or max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not how statistics work. A Gaussian Normal Distribution has a mean and a std but values can be drawn far away from mean +- std, they are just less likeley. As per definition of a normal distribution, 68 % of all values are within +- 1*std, 95 % are within +-2*std and so on. The question is: What do you want to do with outliers? Set them to mean +- std or draw again?

### Case 1: Set outliers to min/max

This is usually unwanted, as this changes your distribution and puts more weight on the lower and upper boundary.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mu = 100
sigma = 7
a = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=2000) # I used a size of 2000 as an example
a[a<(mu-sigma)] = mu-sigma
a[a>(mu+sigma)] = mu+sigma
plt.hist(a, bins=12, edgecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: Outliers set to min/max of the wanted range]

### Case 2: Truncated Normal Distribution

What you usually want is the [Truncated Normal Distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html). It creates a distribution with an upper and a lower boundary. You find this function at the `scipy.stats` module. It works a bit different though: you first create the distribution by normalizing the lower and upper clip and then you create a numer of random variates `rvs` from it like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats

mu = 100
sigma = 7
lower_clip = mu-sigma
upper_clip = mu+sigma
a = stats.truncnorm((lower_clip - mu) / sigma, (upper_clip - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
plt.hist(a.rvs(2000), bins=12, edgecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: Truncated Normal Distribution]

The constant of multiples of sigma is easily implemented. You can just change your lower and upper clip like

```
lower_clip = mu-x*sigma
```

with x being your constant.

Comment: If I drop my requirement of an upper / lower boundary, does np.random.normal produce a normal distribution, not the one above with excessive weight on the ends? I assume it does.

Comment: Yes, that is what `np.random.normal` is there for. But unfortunately you cannot truncate the distribution. If the exact size does not matter, you can also just clip values beyond your boundaries, but that reduces your sample size. Instead of repeating this until you have exactly `m.sum()` values it is better practice to just use `scipy.stats.truncnorm` instead.

Comment: ```@offeltoffel```, understood, and much appreciated.  I have my code working with scipy.stats.truncnorm.